# Method for reading bytes into an hexdigest string

Tags: python, hash, binaryfiles

**I'm reading 16 bytes from a binary buffer** named `raw`:

```
md5 = list(struct.unpack('16B', raw.read(16)))
```

This produces the following list:

```
>>> print(md5)
>>> [25, 94, 158, 89, 108, 25, 125, 20, 138, 164, 84, 137, 250, 82, 150, 202]
```

**I need to build a proper md5 string** that I can then use to compare with any `hexdigest()` from `hashlib.md5()`

Currently I'm doing it this way:

```
md5 = list(struct.unpack('16B', raw.read(16)))
for i, b in enumerate(md5):
    md5[i] = hex(b)
md5 = ''.join(md5).replace('0x', '')
```

This works, but I cannot help but feel I'm missing something. **Is there a more straightforward conversion** between the data in the buffer and the final string?

> **Note:** I understand I have other types of digests. But currently I'm interested in solving the problem for an hexadecimal digest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `hexlify` to convert a `bytes` (Python 3) / binary `str` (Python 2) into a hex string (the string will be `bytes` on Python 3, so we need `.decode('ascii')` there to match against the `hexdigest` that is a `str`).

```
from binascii import hexlify
hex_string = hexlify(raw.read(16)).decode('ascii')

if md5.hexdigest() == hex_string:
    ...
```

Likewise you can compare the raw bytes with the `digest()`; the `hexdigest()` is just 32-character readable representation of the 16-byte value that is the actual MD5 digest sum.

```
the_bytes = raw.read(16)
if md5.digest() == the_bytes:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Antti's method works but seems unnecessarily complicated. It's more direct to just use the [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) method of the bytes type directly:

```
raw.read(16).hex()
```

This is available since Python 3.5. To go back the other way, there is [`bytes.fromhex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex).